# How do I manually send a password reset request in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I  would like to manually send a password reset request to a specific user (not the one currently logged in) from within a controller. I did some digging around in the Laravel code and I searched many articles but I do not get output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
//...
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
//...


public function sendResetEmail(Request $request)
{

        // I will assueme that you already have $email variable

        $response = Password::sendResetLink(['email' => $email], function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
        });

        switch ($response) {
            case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                dump('We have e-mailed your password reset link!');
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                dump('We can\'t find a user with that e-mail address.');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the Password facade

```php
$email = 'example@domain.com';
$response = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::broker()->sendResetLink($email);
$ok = $response == \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::RESET_LINK_SENT;
```